# Unix Shell program to detect which half of month is it. Day of month (dom) -le 16

Tags: shell-script

Ultimate goal is to set up a variable that will be YYYYMMDD where DD is one of two variables (01 or 16)

I am trying to accomplish creating a variable to be one of two values.

here's what I have so far but it's not working:

```
DYA=date +%d 
DYB=IF [["$DYA" -ge 16]]; then 16
else 01
fi
YR=2020
MO=03

FD="$YR$MO$DY"
ECHO "$FD"
```

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/ will pick up the syntax errors you've got. But first of all declare the type of script with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line (it must be `bash` or `zsh` because you're trying to use `[[ ... ]]`).

Answer (score 8):

Using `bash` release 4.2 or later:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf -v day '%(%e)T' -1

if [[ $day -lt 16 ]]; then
    # 1st half of the month
    day=01
else
    # 2nd half of the month
    day=16
fi

printf '%(%Y%m)T%s\n' -1 "$day"
```

The first `printf` prints the current date of the month as a decimal digit into the variable `day`.  The `if` statements constrains this to either `01` or `16` depending on its value.

The last `printf` prints the current year and month, and then adds the `01` or `16` string to the end of this.

The `-1` argument to the `printf` calls makes the `%(...)T` format string use the current time as the timestamp to format (if you're on `bash` 4.3 or later, this is not strictly needed for the first call as it is implicit).

A more compact version for `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf -v day '%(%e)T' -1
printf '%(%Y%m)T%.2d\n' -1 "$(( (day < 16) ? 1 : 16 ))"
```

Here I'm performing the test within an arithmetic expansion using the common [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) `?:`.  This evaluates to the string `1` if `$day` is less than 16, and to `16` if it's greater than 16.  The result of the arithmetic expansion is then formatted into a zero-filled integer and inserted after the current year and month.

---

About your code:

- Note that `[[ ... ]]` needs spaces around both `[[` and `]]` (well, the `;` can occur immediately afterwards without a space since it's a command terminator).
- If you want to put the output of `date`, or any command, into a variable, use a command substitution: `day=$( date +%e )`. This holds true for your `if` statement, if it was to output a value (which it doesn't).
- Unix commands are case sensitive, therefore `ECHO` should probably be `echo`.
- The `%d` time format outputs a zero-filled integer between `01` and `31`.  Note that using such a value in an arithmetic context (the `if` statement) will interpret the values `01` through to `07` as *octal* values, and will produce errors for `08` and `09` (these are invalid octal numbers).  This is why I use `%e` instead to get integers that aren't zero-filled, between `1` and `31`.

About that last point: I could also have used

```
printf -v day '%(%d)T' -1
```

to get zero-filled values between `01` and `31`, but then I would have needed to use

```
if [[ 10#$day -ge 16 ]]; then
```

to force the shell to interpret the string as a decimal integer and not as an octal integer.

---

As a `/bin/sh` script (will also work with `bash` releases before 4.2, e.g. with the default `bash` shell on macOS):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

day=$( date +%e )

if [ "$day" -lt 16 ]; then
    # 1st half of the month
    day=01
else
    # 2nd half of the month
    day=16
fi

date +"%Y%m$day"
```

The standard `sh` shell does not have the `%(...)T` format string of `bash`, so we're forced to use `date` to do the date string formatting.  It also uses `[ ... ]` for tests rather than `[[ ... ]]` (and variables needs to be double quoted within there).

The more compact version for `/bin/sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

day=$( date +%e )
printf '%s%.2d\n' "$(date +%Y%m)" "$(( (day < 16) ? 1 : 16 ))"
```

This more compact version follows from the compact `bash` variation.  The only difference is that `date` is used to format the current year and month.

Comment: Note that `%(...)T` is from ksh93, copied a lot later by bash. (`zsh` also has a `strftime` builtin).

Comment: Why the format `%.2d` ([which is not documented here](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/printf/) and seems to me to be non-standard) instead of the more common `%02d` ?

Comment: @NotAnUnixNazi The page you link to says, about the precision used with `d`: "The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, _it is padded on the left with zeros_". Why do I use this? Well, Stéphane once convinced me it was better or safer, but I can't find a reference to that at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve above:
    #touch mycode.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export DD=$(date +%d)
export YYYY=$(date | awk '{print $6}')
export MM=$(date +%m)
echo "$YYYY$MM$DD"
if [[ $DD -eq 16 || $DD -eq 01  ]];then

 echo "$DD"

else

 echo " The days are not 1st or 16th "

fi


#sh mycode.sh
```

O/P

```
20200303
```

Answer (score 0):

The above worked and here's my code that worked:

```
export day=$(date +%d)
export YR=$(date | awk '{print $6}')
export MM=$(date +%m)
echo $DY
echo "$YR$MM$day"

if [[ $day -ge 16 ]]; then
    day=16
else
day=01
fi
printf '%(%Y%m)T%s\n' -1 "$day"



export FD="$YR$MM$day"
echo $FD
```

Comment: This will break on the 8th and 9th of each month. See my answer for why.  Also, there is no need at all to use `export`.

Comment: If you understand +%d and +%m, what's so hard about +%Y rather than invoking an awk process? And why echo the undefined $DY?

Comment: See also [strftime(3)](https://manpage.me/?strftime) for even **more** options.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd=$(date +%d)
# values 08 and 09 will not work with arithmetic the way you expect
d=${dd#0}         # remove any leading 0
if [ "$d" -ge 16 ] ;then
  half=16
else
  half=01
fi
date "+%Y%m$half"
```

I think this code is the easiest to understand.  The only complication is around the use of shell arithmetic expressions with numbers starting with the digit `0`, which you may not realize unless you've encountered it before.  The format strings for `date` are documented in the `strftime(3)` manpage.  Note that there are implementations of `date` (or `printf`) which don't understand the `%e` conversion specification. The `${dd#0}` construct is documented in the `bash(1)` (or other shell) manpage in the "Parameter Expansion" section.